# Enable version-level immutability support for Azure Storage account with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

Is there a way to enable version-level immutability support and create time-based retention policy for Azure storage account-level with Terraform? All I am trying to do is to enable Access Control under Data Protection and set time based immutability policy. Seems simple, but I cannot find how to do that in TF.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-cli), it appears to me as a newly added feature?

It might take some time to get this packaged into `azurerm` provider. You can create a PR on their [codebase](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm) or create a `feature` request to include this into [azurerm_storage_blob](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob).

In the meantime, you could use `local-exec` on above resource to execute `az-cli` commands.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "immutable-blob" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage blob immutability-policy set \
        --expiry-time 2022-05-20T08:00:00Z \
        --policy-mode Unlocked \
        --container <container> \
        --name <blob-version> \
        --account-name <storage-account> \
        --auth-mode login"
  }
}
```